# How do you adapt sequential search to return mutiple results?

Tags: java, algorithm, search

new to the site, apologies for any mistakes below.

EDIT: Added the code to a [Pastebin](https://pastebin.com/yM6t6Fey). Code has been obscured slightly for my benefit from and employee to customer basis. Apologies if search and replace failed to pick up an instance of employee or emp remaining, can't see one myself.

Am struggling with what I assume is a relatively easy problem. I am trying to adapt a sequential search to return matching first names. Multiple instances of the same first name exist and must be accounted for. I have the template below to work from and have gotten several examples in the past to work without much issue but am having a brain fart when it comes to adapting it for multiple results. Am even unsure of whether to return a series of ints or Strings.

```
static int SequentialSearch(int arr[], int searchKey){
    int n = arr.length;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
       if (arr[i] == searchKey)
       return i;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Can I still return -1 if something is not found while returning the relevant indices in a temporary array or is it a better method to return a string and concatanate the answers. Will the return i; close the loops as soon as the first instance is found or will it complete the for loop?

Have been moving from doing well to struggling within the last month and this question has compounded all of my issues. I am not bound to the template in anyway so if a different one exists for multiple returns I'd be much obliged.

UPDATE: With the code linked above I am getting a response but they're all null

EDIT: In response to a question request below from @MrSmith42 , the expected output would be a return of employee details for any employee with a matching first name. The toString has already been done and now is linked at the start here and it works for a different output (a sorting algorithm) so I would hope to be able to repeat the same steps once the method is correct to get the right output rather painlessly (could be a hope in vain)

Comment: Please add an example input and expected output.

Comment: You might be using the wrong approach, it might help thinking in terms of filtering or mapping. E.g. "filter to the instances that have a match" or "map the instances adding metadata if it's a match or not". If you just want to filter, it's something like `Stream.of(arr).filter(str -> str == searchKey)).collect(Collectors.toSet()).toArray(new String[0]);`. Not sure about the result, I'm a bit rusty in Java.

Comment: @MrSmith42 I've added a lightly edited to cover my tracks version of the code. The expected input would be  '''SequentialSearch(customers, "name");''' and the output would be the customers record matching the name. Have gotten that to work with a sort method so would not expect that to cause and issue and can repeat the same steps to get the output that I used for that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could return a `List<Customer>` with the results or a `null` if there are none. Or just return the list and use the size to determine if there were any results.

```
static List<Customer> SequentialSearch(Customer arr[], String firstName) {
    List<Customer> results = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Customer customer : arr) {
        if (customer.getFirstName().equalsIgnoreCase(firstName)) {
            results.add(customer);
        }
    }
    return results.size() > 0 ? results : null;
}
```

If you're interested, you could also return an array of customers using streams like so.

```
Customer[] results = Arrays.stream(customers).filter(
        c -> c.getFirstName().equalsIgnoreCase(firstName))
            .toArray(Customer[]::new);
// or a list
List<Customer> results = Arrays.stream(customers).filter(
        c -> c.getFirstName().equalsIgnoreCase(firstName))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Yeah, they're string values imported from a file. The file importation is grand, has been working with other methods. I'll give it a shot today after class and let you know how it went, should be about 2 hours. Had not been using the .add method which is much smoother than the temp array I'd been creating and using.

Comment: I tried to implement the code there using the code I added to the original post (pastebin hyperlink) and while it's returning values they are all null so I'm assuming my if() loop is the cause of that . Was running into an error leaving results uninitialized so I did it in the main, hence the nulls. Had assumed they'd get picked up

Comment: @TJones10 It would help greatly if you would include some sample data including what to search for and the expected output.

Comment: I don't mind sharing the csv file but I can't see any option to upload one and am unsure of how to format it. The search for would be any first name as the searchKey, the expected output would be the customer record with fields (emp_no, birth_date,first_name,gender,join_date). I do not think the output will be a problem though as the toString has been written and is working elsewhere for a sort method on the same file with the same toString. It's possible I'm misinterpretting what you're asking for. Sorry, hoping to learn Stack norms quickly.

Comment: I edited the answer. If you simply use the enhanced for loop for arrays you don't need to get its size.  It is much cleaner.

Comment: Dude, it worked perfectly. Thank you so much. I have never seen this structure before, ` for (Customer customer : arr)`, is it a built in method from the arrayList package? The search is working perfectly, I just need to figure out how to print it. You're a lifesaver

Comment: For any `array` of type `T` you can do `for(T v : array)` .  You can also do it for any `List` implementation since they implement the interface `Iterable<T>` which returns an `Iterator<T>`.  Check out the enhanced for each loop in any book on Java or do a web search.